# Read nested JSON nodes/ Keys from OBJ-1 and find those key values from OBJ-2 then update OBJ-1.JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

let obj1 =obj1.json**

```
    {
        "stores": {
            "city1": [
                {
                    "address": null,
                    "firstName": null,
                    "lastName": null
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

let obj2 = obj2.json**

```
{
    "stores": {
        "city1": [
            {
                "address": 13, Landiling,
                "firstName": Robot,
                "lastName": Tom,
                "phone": 12345678,
                "email": test@,
                "manager": tim
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

here is the code I am using to update obj1 values with obj2.

```
 result = Object.keys(obj1.stores.city1[0]);
    for (var i = 0; i< result.length; i++ ) {
    console.log(result[i]);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1.stores.city1[0].result[i]));
    obj1.stores.city1[0].result[i]=obj2.stores.city1[0].result[i];
    }
```

I am able to get the child Keys from obj1, using above code, but not able to update the values back to obj1. as it showing it as 'i' is not defined or received undefined result.

Comment: `Object.keys` returns array of **strings** like `["address", "firstName", "lastName"]`. Hence the `result[i]` will be `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to know the current city key to lookup the city in the update object.

1. Loop over the city keys
2. Loop over the cities by the city key
3. Assign the update object at the corresponding index in the city array

Not sure if you want to copy all the properties over, but you did not have example output.

```js
const toBeUpdated = {
  "stores": {
    "city1": [{
      "address": null,
      "firstName": null,
      "lastName": null
    }]
  }
}

const updateInfo = {
  "stores": {
    "city1": [{
      "address": "13, Landiling",
      "firstName": "Robot",
      "lastName": "Tom",
      "phone": "12345678",
      "email": "test@",
      "manager": "tim"
    }]
  }
}

Object.keys(toBeUpdated.stores).forEach(cityKey => {
  toBeUpdated.stores[cityKey].forEach((city, index) => {
    Object.assign(city, { ...updateInfo.stores[cityKey][index] });
  });
});

console.log(toBeUpdated);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code a little bit to make it run on my local machine. Here is the working code which is achieving what you are trying to achieve.

```
const obj1 = {
  stores: {
    city1: [
      {
        address: null,
        firstName: null,
        lastName: null
      }
    ]
  }
}
const obj2 = {
  stores: {
    city1: [
      {
        address: '13, Landiling',
        firstName: 'Robot',
        lastName: 'Tom',
        phone: 12345678,
        email: 'test@',
        manager: 'tim'
      }
    ]
  }
}

const result = Object.keys(obj1.stores.city1[0])
console.log('Keys: ', result)

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  console.log('Key: ', result[i])
  console.log('Value:', JSON.stringify(obj1.stores.city1[0][i]))
  obj1.stores.city1[0][result[i]] = obj2.stores.city1[0][result[i]]
}

console.log('object 1: ', JSON.stringify(obj1))
console.log('object 2: ', JSON.stringify(obj2))
```

The following line of your code:

```
obj1.stores.city1[0].result[i]=obj2.stores.city1[0].result[i];
```

Is being translated as

```
obj1.stores.city1[0].result.<value of i> = obj2.stores.city1[0].result.<value of i>;
```

You're looking for **result** property on the city1[0] object which doesn't exists then you are trying to access a **number <value of i> property** on **result** object (which itself is undefined). So you are trying to access undefined property of undefined object. That's why you are unable to change the **obj1**. I hope my answer clarifies.

Comment: Thank you, but need to compare the Key names and then only assign the values. The order of keys are not always same. Need to look for exact key and assign the values back. Appreciate any help.

Comment: @Siri if you need any help then drop me a message and we can proceed from there: https://www.linkedin.com/in/rafay-hassan/

Comment: @Siri I am not telling you the logic what you need to do but what was wrong with your code. If you need to compare keys you can.